# Will the flashback desktop environment be able for installation in future versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

Will the flashback desktop environment be able for installation in future versions of Ubuntu? (In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and future versions)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Mate is what you're looking for. Mate is a fork of the original Gnome 2 desktop and via the Ubuntu Mate project is now an official desktop respin.

And yes, they're releasing a 16.04 version. Not sure what their Mate package support is like (don't know if it's a long-term-release) but all the other core applications will be.

Answer (score 3):

The Flashback (previously *Fallback*) session is [developed by GNOME](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback). As long as they continue to develop it, it is a fair bet that Ubuntu will continue to make it available. There is no indication that GNOME Flashback will be discontinued in the foreseeable future. As for 16.04, it is [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome-flashback).

Answer (score 0):

see discussion here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291032

It will be in 16.04. I believe this is gnome function not Ubuntu.

Even if it is not there anymore you can always install a lighter desktop environment or use a windows manager only.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.